# Min expected input to be a list but got the number ... instead

Tags: netlogo

I have a twist on the usual thread. I am working on a labor market where the firm will pick the worker asking for the lower firm out of all close workers until its capital is exhausted or there are no more unemployed workers available.

The problem is, [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) min command does not like it when there is only one worker left to choose from. This causes the error message:

```
 MIN expected input to be a list but got the number 98.22043664491966 instead.
```

the code is as follows:

```
while [ (capital > min-wage) and (local-number > 2) ] [
  let min-worker min-one-of local-unenmp [ salary ]
  let wage [salary] of min-worker
    ask  min-worker [
      set unemployed? false
      set aggregate-employed (aggregate-employed + 1)
      set wealth (wealth + wage)
      set labor-check1 (labor-check1 + 1)
      set local-unenmp local-unenmp with [self != myself]
      set local-number count local-unenmp
    ]
    set working (working + 1)
    set capital (capital - wage)
    if capital <= min-wage [stop]
    if local-number < 3 [stop]
]
set labor working
set labor-check2 (labor-check2 + 1)
```

]

Comment: Is the error guiding you to the line `let min-worker min-one-of local-unenmp [ salary ]`?
I am confused, as you exclude the cases when there is only one worker left, by asking `(local-number > 2)`, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: You are right, the error was actually sending me to another min use later in the code but in the same procedure which was used incorrectly. Thank you! (should I delete this post?)